# How to create a Android WifiConfiguration and access wifi with username/password

Tags: android, configuration, wifi, account

WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "ssid";
    conf.preSharedKey = "\"password\"";
    conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;

```
conf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);

conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40); 
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);

conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);

conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);

int res = wifi.addNetwork(conf);
boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);
```

---

This wifi access point need a username + password to connect to, but I can't find any way to set the password to it. I think this is the problem so that I can't create it successfully.

Please help me on this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you have set [WifiConfiguration.wepKeys](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html#wepKeys)

```
conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"password\"";
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android/4374934#4374934) is a really good example.