# How to programmatically create and read WEP/EAP WiFi configurations in Android

Tags: android, wifi

How can I programmatically create and read WEP/EAP WiFi configurations in Android?

Comment: Android adds WifiEnterpriseConfig to support EAP wifi in API 18

Answer (score 110, accepted):

***Part 1: Creating a WEP WiFi configuration programmatically***

This is pretty much straightforward, [WifiConfiguration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html) exposes the interface to create the same. Here is the sample code:

```
void saveWepConfig()
{
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration(); 
    wc.SSID = "\"SSID_NAME\""; //IMP! This should be in Quotes!!
    wc.hiddenSSID = true;
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;     
    wc.priority = 40;
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN); 
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
           
    wc.wepKeys[0] = "\"aaabbb1234\""; //This is the WEP Password
    wc.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
                         
    WifiManager  wifiManag = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    boolean res1 = wifiManag.setWifiEnabled(true);
    int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res );
    boolean es = wifi.saveConfiguration();
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "saveConfiguration returned " + es );
    boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);   
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );  
            
}
```

Following the permissions needed in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE">
    </uses-permission>
```

***Part 2: Read a WEP WiFi configuration programmatically***
Straighforward again. Here is the sample code:

```
    void readWepConfig()
    { 
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
        List<WifiConfiguration> item = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
        int i = item.size();
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "NO OF CONFIG " + i );
        Iterator<WifiConfiguration> iter =  item.iterator();
        WifiConfiguration config = item.get(0);
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "SSID" + config.SSID);
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "PASSWORD" + config.preSharedKey);
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "ALLOWED ALGORITHMS");
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "LEAP" + config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.get(AuthAlgorithm.LEAP));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "OPEN" + config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.get(AuthAlgorithm.OPEN));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "SHARED" + config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.get(AuthAlgorithm.SHARED));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "GROUP CIPHERS");
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "CCMP" + config.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.CCMP));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "TKIP" + config.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.TKIP));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "WEP104" + config.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.WEP104));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "WEP40" + config.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.WEP40));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "KEYMGMT");
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "IEEE8021X" + config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "NONE" + config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.NONE));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "WPA_EAP" + config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "WPA_PSK" + config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "PairWiseCipher");
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "CCMP" + config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.get(PairwiseCipher.CCMP));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "NONE" + config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.get(PairwiseCipher.NONE));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "TKIP" + config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.get(PairwiseCipher.TKIP));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "Protocols");
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "RSN" + config.allowedProtocols.get(Protocol.RSN));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "WPA" + config.allowedProtocols.get(Protocol.WPA));
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "WEP Key Strings");
        String[] wepKeys = config.wepKeys;
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "WEP KEY 0" + wepKeys[0]);
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "WEP KEY 1" + wepKeys[1]);
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "WEP KEY 2" + wepKeys[2]);
        Log.d("WifiPreference", "WEP KEY 3" + wepKeys[3]);
    }
```

***Part 3: Read a EAP WiFi Configuration programmatically***
Now this is tricky. You can find the code which saves a EAP WiFi configuration through the vanilla Android UI in [WifiDialog.java](http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/settings/wifi/WifiDialog.java.html). Well easy enough We can use the same code in our Application, Well NO! If you happen to try this you will get errors saying cannot find the symbols `eap`, `phase`, `client_cert` and so on. A little detailed investigation tells us [EnterpriseField](http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/android/android/5/p/android.net.wifi/c/WifiConfiguration) `is private` inside `WiFiConfiguration` class and all the symbols we cannot find are of the type `EnterpriseField`. Well we've hit a roadblock, We need these fields for reading/saving a EAP config but we don't have programmatic access to them!

***`Java Reflection API` to the rescue***
Well I am not a Java expert so I wont be getting in to details of Reflection API as such and you can google for tutorials or get more information [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).
To keep it Short and Sweet, Reflection API allows you to inspect classes, interfaces, fields and methods at runtime, without knowing the names of the classes, methods etc. at compile time. It is also possible to instantiate new objects, invoke methods and get/set field values using reflection.And, Importantly ***Reflection can help you access private data members inside a class*** Well this is what we need don't we? :)

Let's check the code example now which shows how to read a EAP WiFi configuration using Reflection Api. As a bonus the snippet will log the config to a file and save it on the SD Card....pretty slick ..eh ;) A little bit of overview of Reflection Api and I am sure grasping the code below is easy.

```
    private static final String INT_PRIVATE_KEY = "private_key";
    private static final String INT_PHASE2 = "phase2";
    private static final String INT_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String INT_IDENTITY = "identity";
    private static final String INT_EAP = "eap";
    private static final String INT_CLIENT_CERT = "client_cert";
    private static final String INT_CA_CERT = "ca_cert";
    private static final String INT_ANONYMOUS_IDENTITY = "anonymous_identity";
    final String INT_ENTERPRISEFIELD_NAME = "android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration$EnterpriseField";
```

This is the code to create a logfile on to SD card before calling the `readEapConfig()` function.

```
        BufferedWriter out = null;
        try 
        {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "SD CARD mounted and writable? " + root.canWrite(), 5000);
            toast.show();
            if (root.canWrite())
            {
                File gpxfile = new File(root, "ReadConfigLog.txt");
                FileWriter gpxwriter = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
                out = new BufferedWriter(gpxwriter);
                out.write("Hello world");
                //out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Problem reading SD CARD", 3000);
            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, "Please take logs using Logcat", 5000);
            Log.e("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Now the `readEapConfig()` function itself:

```
    void readEapConfig(BufferedWriter out)
    {
        /*Get the WifiService */        
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        /*Get All WIfi configurations*/
        List<WifiConfiguration> configList = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
        /*Now we need to search appropriate configuration i.e. with name SSID_Name*/
        for(int i = 0;i<configList.size();i++)
        {
            if(configList.get(i).SSID.contentEquals("\"SSID_NAME\""))
            {
                /*We found the appropriate config now read all config details*/
                Iterator<WifiConfiguration> iter =  configList.iterator();
                WifiConfiguration config = configList.get(i);
                
                /*I dont think these fields have anything to do with EAP config but still will
                 * print these to be on safe side*/
                try {
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[SSID]" + config.SSID);
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[SSID]" + config.SSID);
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[BSSID]" + config.BSSID);
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" +"[BSSID]" + config.BSSID);
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[HIDDEN SSID]" + config.hiddenSSID);
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[HIDDEN SSID]" + config.hiddenSSID);
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[PASSWORD]" + config.preSharedKey);
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>"+ "[PASSWORD]" + config.preSharedKey);
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[ALLOWED ALGORITHMS]");
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>"+ "[ALLOWED ALGORITHMS]");
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[LEAP]" + config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.get(AuthAlgorithm.LEAP));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[LEAP]" + config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.get(AuthAlgorithm.LEAP));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[OPEN]" + config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.get(AuthAlgorithm.OPEN));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[OPEN]" + config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.get(AuthAlgorithm.OPEN));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[SHARED]" + config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.get(AuthAlgorithm.SHARED));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[SHARED]" + config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.get(AuthAlgorithm.SHARED));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[GROUP CIPHERS]");
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[GROUP CIPHERS]");
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[CCMP]" + config.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.CCMP));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[CCMP]" + config.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.CCMP));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" , "[TKIP]" + config.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.TKIP));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>"+ "[TKIP]" + config.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.TKIP));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[WEP104]" + config.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.WEP104));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[WEP104]" + config.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.WEP104));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[WEP40]" + config.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.WEP40));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[WEP40]" + config.allowedGroupCiphers.get(GroupCipher.WEP40));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[KEYMGMT]");
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[KEYMGMT]");
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[IEEE8021X]" + config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>"+ "[IEEE8021X]" + config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[NONE]" + config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.NONE));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[NONE]" + config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.NONE));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[WPA_EAP]" + config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[WPA_EAP]" + config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[WPA_PSK]" + config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[WPA_PSK]" + config.allowedKeyManagement.get(KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[PairWiseCipher]");
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[PairWiseCipher]");
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[CCMP]" + config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.get(PairwiseCipher.CCMP));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[CCMP]" + config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.get(PairwiseCipher.CCMP));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[NONE]" + config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.get(PairwiseCipher.NONE));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[NONE]" + config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.get(PairwiseCipher.NONE));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[TKIP]" + config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.get(PairwiseCipher.TKIP));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[TKIP]" + config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.get(PairwiseCipher.TKIP));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[Protocols]");
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[Protocols]");
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[RSN]" + config.allowedProtocols.get(Protocol.RSN));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[RSN]" + config.allowedProtocols.get(Protocol.RSN));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[WPA]" + config.allowedProtocols.get(Protocol.WPA));
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[WPA]" + config.allowedProtocols.get(Protocol.WPA));
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[PRE_SHARED_KEY]" + config.preSharedKey);
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[PRE_SHARED_KEY]" + config.preSharedKey);
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[WEP Key Strings]");
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[WEP Key Strings]");
                String[] wepKeys = config.wepKeys;
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[WEP KEY 0]" + wepKeys[0]);
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[WEP KEY 0]" + wepKeys[0]);
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[WEP KEY 1]" + wepKeys[1]);
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[WEP KEY 1]" + wepKeys[1]);
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[WEP KEY 2]" + wepKeys[2]);
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[WEP KEY 2]" + wepKeys[2]);
                Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[WEP KEY 3]" + wepKeys[3]);
                out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[WEP KEY 3]" + wepKeys[3]);
                
                }
                catch(IOException e) 
                {
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to write Logs to ReadConfigLog.txt", 3000);
                    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, "Please take logs using Logcat", 5000);
                    Log.e("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "Could not write to ReadConfigLog.txt" + e.getMessage());
                }
                /*reflection magic*/
                /*These are the fields we are really interested in*/
                try 
                {
                    // Let the magic start
                    Class[] wcClasses = WifiConfiguration.class.getClasses();
                    // null for overzealous java compiler
                    Class wcEnterpriseField = null;

                    for (Class wcClass : wcClasses)
                        if (wcClass.getName().equals(INT_ENTERPRISEFIELD_NAME)) 
                        {
                            wcEnterpriseField = wcClass;
                            break;
                        }
                    boolean noEnterpriseFieldType = false; 
                    if(wcEnterpriseField == null)
                        noEnterpriseFieldType = true; // Cupcake/Donut access enterprise settings directly
                    
                    Field wcefAnonymousId = null, wcefCaCert = null, wcefClientCert = null, wcefEap = null, wcefIdentity = null, wcefPassword = null, wcefPhase2 = null, wcefPrivateKey = null;
                    Field[] wcefFields = WifiConfiguration.class.getFields();
                    // Dispatching Field vars
                    for (Field wcefField : wcefFields) 
                    {
                        if (wcefField.getName().trim().equals(INT_ANONYMOUS_IDENTITY))
                            wcefAnonymousId = wcefField;
                        else if (wcefField.getName().trim().equals(INT_CA_CERT))
                            wcefCaCert = wcefField;
                        else if (wcefField.getName().trim().equals(INT_CLIENT_CERT))
                            wcefClientCert = wcefField;
                        else if (wcefField.getName().trim().equals(INT_EAP))
                            wcefEap = wcefField;
                        else if (wcefField.getName().trim().equals(INT_IDENTITY))
                            wcefIdentity = wcefField;
                        else if (wcefField.getName().trim().equals(INT_PASSWORD))
                            wcefPassword = wcefField;
                        else if (wcefField.getName().trim().equals(INT_PHASE2))
                            wcefPhase2 = wcefField;
                        else if (wcefField.getName().trim().equals(INT_PRIVATE_KEY))
                            wcefPrivateKey = wcefField;
                    }
                Method wcefValue = null;
                if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
                {
                for(Method m: wcEnterpriseField.getMethods())
                //System.out.println(m.getName());
                if(m.getName().trim().equals("value")){
                    wcefValue = m;
                    break;
                }
                }
                
                /*EAP Method*/
                String result = null;
                Object obj = null;
                if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
                {
                    obj = wcefValue.invoke(wcefEap.get(config), null);
                    String retval = (String)obj;
                    Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[EAP METHOD]" + retval);
                    out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[EAP METHOD]" + retval);
                }
                else
                {
                    obj = wcefEap.get(config);
                    String retval = (String)obj;                        
                }
                
                /*phase 2*/
                if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
                {
                    result = (String) wcefValue.invoke(wcefPhase2.get(config), null);
                    Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[EAP PHASE 2 AUTHENTICATION]" + result);
                    out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[EAP PHASE 2 AUTHENTICATION]" + result);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = (String) wcefPhase2.get(config);
                }

                /*Anonymous Identity*/
                if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
                {
                    result = (String) wcefValue.invoke(wcefAnonymousId.get(config),null);
                    Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[EAP ANONYMOUS IDENTITY]" + result);
                    out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[EAP ANONYMOUS IDENTITY]" + result);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = (String) wcefAnonymousId.get(config);
                }
                
                /*CA certificate*/
                if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
                {
                    result = (String) wcefValue.invoke(wcefCaCert.get(config), null);
                    Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[EAP CA CERTIFICATE]" + result);
                    out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[EAP CA CERTIFICATE]" + result);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = (String)wcefCaCert.get(config);

                }
                
                /*private key*/
                if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
                {
                    result = (String) wcefValue.invoke(wcefPrivateKey.get(config),null);
                    Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[EAP PRIVATE KEY]" + result);
                    out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[EAP PRIVATE KEY]" + result);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = (String)wcefPrivateKey.get(config);
                }

                /*Identity*/
                if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
                {
                    result = (String) wcefValue.invoke(wcefIdentity.get(config), null);
                    Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[EAP IDENTITY]" + result);
                    out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[EAP IDENTITY]" + result);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = (String)wcefIdentity.get(config);
                }
                
                /*Password*/
                if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
                {
                    result = (String) wcefValue.invoke(wcefPassword.get(config), null);
                    Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[EAP PASSWORD]" + result);
                    out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[EAP PASSWORD]" + result);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = (String)wcefPassword.get(config);
                }
                    
                /*client certificate*/
                if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
                {
                    result = (String) wcefValue.invoke(wcefClientCert.get(config), null);
                    Log.d("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "[EAP CLIENT CERT]" + result);
                    out.write("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "[EAP CLIENT CERT]" + result);
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(this, "All config data logged to ReadConfigLog.txt", 3000);
                    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, "Extract ReadConfigLog.txt from SD CARD", 5000);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = (String)wcefClientCert.get(config);
                }
                
                out.close();
                    
                }
                catch(IOException e) 
                {
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to write Logs to ReadConfigLog.txt", 3000);
                    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, "Please take logs using Logcat", 5000);
                    Log.e("<<<<<<<<<<WifiPreference>>>>>>>>>>>>", "Could not write to ReadConfigLog.txt" + e.getMessage());
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

***Please see Part 4 [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programmatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android/4375874#4375874)***

Comment: I tried doing this, but for some reason, it creates a new interface in Wireless networks (with a comment saying Not reachable), but the SSID is exactly same as the original network. Any help in this regard?

Comment: @nithinreddy: I am afraid I don't dabble in Android anymore(haven't for a quite a long time) so doubt If I can provide any help.AFAIR, You should not have two configs with the same SSID name,As for not reachable problem, Check your configuration parameters. My guess is there might be a mismatch there somewhere..Make a config manually, check it connects then Read the config params programatically(see Howto? details in answers above)& then use those parameters to create a config programatically.Probably the config that connects is not the one you added programatically

Comment: @AlokSave This would be a great, when you will give steps about certificates. (for EAP WIFI). I have some questions how can I create those certificates and how can I install them programatically. Actually I am googling for last two days but didn't find the way to install certificate programatically. So please share your knowledge please.

Comment: @Tinfu: Someone rejected the edit you added on another answer. Please add your edit again.I will accept and approve the same.

Comment: I want to confirm there's something wrong with WEP on Android (4.1 here) when doing it programmatically. If I do this manually in the system's settings however, it works. I tried everything for days, then changed to WPA, and it worked in both cases (manually and programmatically). So for WEP: I did read the WEP structure when created manually (which works) to reproduce it exactly programmatically, but no way, it just stay forever in the "OBTAINING_IPADDR" state. I found another person with the same issue, so be warned. Infos here are great, but something's is missing (at least in some cases).

Comment: Why do you use AuthAlgorithm.OPEN for WEP?, the android documentation says "Open System authentication (required for WPA/WPA2)"

Comment: Protocol.RSN and Protocol.WPA is also only needed for WAP, so why do you use it for WEP?

Comment: I unable to find WifiDialog.java. and face issue to add CA Certificate can you hep me please

Answer (score 37):

I ran out of edit space; adding the remaining part here:

***Part 4: Save a EAP WiFi configuration programmatically***

If you already read the part 3, you already understand the Reflection magic that works here, If you are directly jumping to this section please read the introduction before the code snippet in part 3 and you will be up to speed to breeze through the code here!

```
void saveEapConfig(String passString, String userName)
    {
    /********************************Configuration Strings****************************************************/
    final String ENTERPRISE_EAP = "TLS";
    final String ENTERPRISE_CLIENT_CERT = "keystore://USRCERT_CertificateName";
    final String ENTERPRISE_PRIV_KEY = "USRPKEY_CertificateName";
    //CertificateName = Name given to the certificate while installing it

    /*Optional Params- My wireless Doesn't use these*/
    final String ENTERPRISE_PHASE2 = "";
    final String ENTERPRISE_ANON_IDENT = "ABC";
    final String ENTERPRISE_CA_CERT = ""; // If required: "keystore://CACERT_CaCertificateName"
    /********************************Configuration Strings****************************************************/

    /*Create a WifiConfig*/
    WifiConfiguration selectedConfig = new WifiConfiguration();

    /*AP Name*/
    selectedConfig.SSID = "\"SSID_Name\"";

    /*Priority*/
    selectedConfig.priority = 40;

    /*Enable Hidden SSID*/
    selectedConfig.hiddenSSID = true;

    /*Key Mgmnt*/
    selectedConfig.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
    selectedConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);
    selectedConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);

    /*Group Ciphers*/
    selectedConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
    selectedConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    selectedConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    selectedConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
    selectedConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);

    /*Pairwise ciphers*/
    selectedConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
    selectedConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    selectedConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);

    /*Protocols*/
    selectedConfig.allowedProtocols.clear();
    selectedConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    selectedConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);

    // Enterprise Settings
    // Reflection magic here too, need access to non-public APIs
    try {
        // Let the magic start
        Class[] wcClasses = WifiConfiguration.class.getClasses();
        // null for overzealous java compiler
        Class wcEnterpriseField = null;

        for (Class wcClass : wcClasses)
            if (wcClass.getName().equals(INT_ENTERPRISEFIELD_NAME)) 
            {
                wcEnterpriseField = wcClass;
                break;
            }
        boolean noEnterpriseFieldType = false; 
        if(wcEnterpriseField == null)
            noEnterpriseFieldType = true; // Cupcake/Donut access enterprise settings directly

        Field wcefAnonymousId = null, wcefCaCert = null, wcefClientCert = null, wcefEap = null, wcefIdentity = null, wcefPassword = null, wcefPhase2 = null, wcefPrivateKey = null, wcefEngine = null, wcefEngineId = null;
        Field[] wcefFields = WifiConfiguration.class.getFields();
        // Dispatching Field vars
        for (Field wcefField : wcefFields) 
        {
            if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_ANONYMOUS_IDENTITY))
                wcefAnonymousId = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_CA_CERT))
                wcefCaCert = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_CLIENT_CERT))
                wcefClientCert = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_EAP))
                wcefEap = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_IDENTITY))
                wcefIdentity = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_PASSWORD))
                wcefPassword = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_PHASE2))
                wcefPhase2 = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_PRIVATE_KEY))
                wcefPrivateKey = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals("engine"))
                wcefEngine = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals("engine_id"))
                wcefEngineId = wcefField;
        }


        Method wcefSetValue = null;
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType){
        for(Method m: wcEnterpriseField.getMethods())
            //System.out.println(m.getName());
            if(m.getName().trim().equals("setValue"))
                wcefSetValue = m;
        }


        /*EAP Method*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
        {
                wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefEap.get(selectedConfig), ENTERPRISE_EAP);
        }
        else
        {
                wcefEap.set(selectedConfig, ENTERPRISE_EAP);
        }
        /*EAP Phase 2 Authentication*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
        {
                wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefPhase2.get(selectedConfig), ENTERPRISE_PHASE2);
        }
        else
        {
              wcefPhase2.set(selectedConfig, ENTERPRISE_PHASE2);
        }
        /*EAP Anonymous Identity*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
        {
                wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefAnonymousId.get(selectedConfig), ENTERPRISE_ANON_IDENT);
        }
        else
        {
              wcefAnonymousId.set(selectedConfig, ENTERPRISE_ANON_IDENT);
        }
        /*EAP CA Certificate*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
        {
                wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefCaCert.get(selectedConfig), ENTERPRISE_CA_CERT);
        }
        else
        {
              wcefCaCert.set(selectedConfig, ENTERPRISE_CA_CERT);
        }               
        /*EAP Private key*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
        {
                wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefPrivateKey.get(selectedConfig), ENTERPRISE_PRIV_KEY);
        }
        else
        {
              wcefPrivateKey.set(selectedConfig, ENTERPRISE_PRIV_KEY);
        }               
        /*EAP Identity*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
        {
                wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefIdentity.get(selectedConfig), userName);
        }
        else
        {
              wcefIdentity.set(selectedConfig, userName);
        }               
        /*EAP Password*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
        {
                wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefPassword.get(selectedConfig), passString);
        }
        else
        {
              wcefPassword.set(selectedConfig, passString);
        }               
        /*EAp Client certificate*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
        {
            wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefClientCert.get(selectedConfig), ENTERPRISE_CLIENT_CERT);
        }
        else
        {
              wcefClientCert.set(selectedConfig, ENTERPRISE_CLIENT_CERT);
        }
        /*Engine fields*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType)
        {
           wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefEngine.get(wifiConf), "1");
           wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefEngineId.get(wifiConf), "keystore");
        }

        // Adhoc for CM6
        // if non-CM6 fails gracefully thanks to nested try-catch

        try{
        Field wcAdhoc = WifiConfiguration.class.getField("adhocSSID");
        Field wcAdhocFreq = WifiConfiguration.class.getField("frequency");
        //wcAdhoc.setBoolean(selectedConfig, prefs.getBoolean(PREF_ADHOC,
        //      false));
        wcAdhoc.setBoolean(selectedConfig, false);
        int freq = 2462;    // default to channel 11
        //int freq = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(PREF_ADHOC_FREQUENCY,
        //"2462"));     // default to channel 11
        //System.err.println(freq);
        wcAdhocFreq.setInt(selectedConfig, freq); 
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        // FIXME As above, what should I do here?
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    WifiManager wifiManag = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    boolean res1 = wifiManag.setWifiEnabled(true);
    int res = wifiManag.addNetwork(selectedConfig);
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res );
    boolean b = wifiManag.enableNetwork(selectedConfig.networkId, false);
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );
    boolean c = wifiManag.saveConfiguration();
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "Save configuration returned " + c );
    boolean d = wifiManag.enableNetwork(res, true);   
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + d );  
}
```

Comment: If I use this code on my app, can I still publish it on Google Market?

Comment: @abresas: As I have mentioned in the answer, this source was developed by me getting information from various sources on the internet and long back, at that time a new SDK was released and not much information was available about these.I do not know the current Android situation as I do not currently work with Android.Also, I hold no copyright over this code and I do not have any problems in anyone using it, that being the reason for posting it here in first place but I do not know about thoughts/outlook of the sources which helped me in writing this source.

Comment: `Field wcAdhoc = WifiConfiguration.class.getField("adhocSSID");
            Field wcAdhocFreq = WifiConfiguration.class.getField("frequency");`. These members are not in WifiConfiguration.java. The code is giving me an exception `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: adhocSSID `. Please help.

Comment: Is this still working? I was trying to configure a EAP connection with this code but although the connection is created, the identity and password fields are not filled.

Comment: @TiagoBabo: I don't know for sure. The version of code I uploaded used to work precisely. But Tinfu updated the code for latter versions of Android platform. You might want to check the older code through edit history and check if it works correctly.

Comment: I am using Android 4.1.2 so maybe this code no longer works with recent versions.

Comment: I've noticed it not working for 4.1 or 4.2. The line `wcefPrivateKey.get(selectedConfig)` throws a `NullPointerException`. Any luck from anyone else?

Comment: Could someone provide info about this field: `final String ENTERPRISE_CLIENT_CERT = "keystore://USRCERT_CertificateName"`. It mean you previously install cert using KeyChain? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can I use above code to connect to EAP of sim type?

Comment: Field[] wcefFields = WifiConfiguration.class.getFields();
not returning all the fields which we require. Please check below fields. I have spent whole day but not able to figure it out.

    private static final String INT_PRIVATE_KEY = "private_key";
    private static final String INT_PHASE2 = "phase2";
    private static final String INT_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String INT_IDENTITY = "identity";
    private static final String INT_EAP = "eap";
    private static final String INT_CLIENT_CERT = "client_cert";
    all the fileds required

Comment: It seems reflection technique is not working for above fields. Please some one can help me?

Comment: You are right @PrashanthDebbadwar, it does not work for API 18+ anymore. This code only works for the earlier versions.

Answer (score 6):

Android has added an API to JellyBean 4.3. You must use this option if you want to configure WIFI on API 18:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiEnterpriseConfig.html

Comment: this is more than just "another option". android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration$EnterpriseField no longer exists (presumably as of API 18 where they added WifiEnterpriseConfig) so Alok's solution breaks. both solutions are now required for apps that want to run on API 18+ and API 17-.

Answer (score 1):

Part 4 started me off on the right path! However i wanted to create a TTLS rather than TLS config here is how i did it!

```
    /********************************Configuration Strings****************************************************/
    final String ENTERPRISE_EAP = "TTLS";

    /*Optional Params- My wireless Doesn't use these*/
    final String ENTERPRISE_PHASE2 = "PAP";
    final String ENTERPRISE_ANON_IDENT = "ABC";
    final String ENTERPRISE_CA_CERT = "";
    /********************************Configuration Strings****************************************************/

    /*Create a WifiConfig*/
    WifiConfiguration selectedConfig = new WifiConfiguration();

    /*AP Name*/
    selectedConfig.SSID = "\"EAP_SSID_TEST_CONFIG\"";

    /*Priority*/
    selectedConfig.priority = 40;

    /*Enable Hidden SSID*/
    selectedConfig.hiddenSSID = false;

    /*Key Mgmnt*/
    selectedConfig.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
    selectedConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);
    selectedConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);

    /*Group Ciphers*/
    selectedConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
    selectedConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    selectedConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    selectedConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
    selectedConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);

    /*Pairwise ciphers*/
    selectedConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
    selectedConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    selectedConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);

    /*Protocols*/
    selectedConfig.allowedProtocols.clear();
    selectedConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    selectedConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);

    // Enterprise Settings
    // Reflection magic here too, need access to non-public APIs
    try {
        // Let the magic start
        Class[] wcClasses = WifiConfiguration.class.getClasses();
        // null for overzealous java compiler
        Class wcEnterpriseField = null;

        for (Class wcClass : wcClasses)
            if (wcClass.getName().equals(INT_ENTERPRISEFIELD_NAME)) 
            {
                wcEnterpriseField = wcClass;
                break;
            }
        boolean noEnterpriseFieldType = false; 
        if(wcEnterpriseField == null)
            noEnterpriseFieldType = true; // Cupcake/Donut access enterprise settings directly

        Field wcefAnonymousId = null, wcefCaCert = null, wcefClientCert = null, wcefEap = null, wcefIdentity = null, wcefPassword = null, wcefPhase2 = null, wcefPrivateKey = null;
        Field[] wcefFields = WifiConfiguration.class.getFields();
        // Dispatching Field vars
        for (Field wcefField : wcefFields) 
        {
            if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_ANONYMOUS_IDENTITY))
                wcefAnonymousId = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_CA_CERT))
                wcefCaCert = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_CLIENT_CERT))
                wcefClientCert = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_EAP))
                wcefEap = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_IDENTITY))
                wcefIdentity = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_PASSWORD))
                wcefPassword = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_PHASE2))
                wcefPhase2 = wcefField;
            else if (wcefField.getName().equals(INT_PRIVATE_KEY))
                wcefPrivateKey = wcefField;
        }


        Method wcefSetValue = null;
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType){
        for(Method m: wcEnterpriseField.getMethods())
            //System.out.println(m.getName());
            if(m.getName().trim().equals("setValue"))
                wcefSetValue = m;
        }


        /*EAP Method*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType){
            wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefEap.get(selectedConfig), ENTERPRISE_EAP);
        }
        /*EAP Phase 2 Authentication*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType){
            wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefPhase2.get(selectedConfig), ENTERPRISE_PHASE2);
        }
        /*EAP Anonymous Identity*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType){
            wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefAnonymousId.get(selectedConfig), ENTERPRISE_ANON_IDENT);
        }
        /*EAP CA Certificate*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType){
            wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefCaCert.get(selectedConfig), ENTERPRISE_CA_CERT);
        }


        /*EAP Identity*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType){
            wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefIdentity.get(selectedConfig), "test user name");
        }
        /*EAP Password*/
        if(!noEnterpriseFieldType){
            wcefSetValue.invoke(wcefPassword.get(selectedConfig), "test password");
        }


        try{

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    WifiManager wifiManag = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    boolean res1 = wifiManag.setWifiEnabled(true);
    int res = wifiManag.addNetwork(selectedConfig);
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res );
//        boolean b = wifiManag.enableNetwork(selectedConfig.networkId, false);
//        Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );
//        boolean c = wifiManag.saveConfiguration();
//        Log.d("WifiPreference", "Save configuration returned " + c );
//        boolean d = wifiManag.enableNetwork(res, true);   
//        Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + d ); 


}
```

Hope this helps some one. 
@Android learner I removed the bit about adHocFrequency and SSID as they were causing crashes but my results were still good without them.

Answer (score 0):

The WEP keys are masked, so it is not possible to read them with the mentioned code

```
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "WEP KEY 0" + wepKeys[0]);
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "WEP KEY 1" + wepKeys[1]);
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "WEP KEY 2" + wepKeys[2]);
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "WEP KEY 3" + wepKeys[3]);
```

Is there any way to solve this in same way as the EAP solution?
With reflection?

Comment: for eap also reflection is not working for particular fields which we require. did you solve your problem?