# Android WPA/8021X self signed cert

Tags: android, wifi, x509certificate

Im writing a app to allow users to connect android to enterprise wireless networks easily using  PEAP or TTLS and a cert.

I can add a EAP based wifi profile and get it to connect wpa_supplicant to the network using the correct credentials and cert. Partially thanks to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android)

The installation of a cert is proving difficult though.

At the moment i am installing the cert using WebVeiw in the app to open a php file with the appropriate header and cert in. See [x509 header](http://groups.google.com/group/android-security-discuss/browse_thread/thread/0bf726de4f5275a3/391b900631d7f358). This bring up a certManager instance which requires the user name the cert.

**Is there a neater way to install a CA cert on android?**

From my searching so far, im guessing not.

Answer (score 0):

OK since i posted this Ice Cream Sandwich 4.x has come out with a solution in the KeyStore API:

```
enter code here
Certificate cert = null;
//some code to get the cert
Intent intent = new Intent("android.credentials.INSTALL");
intent.putExtra("name", "Swansea Uni WiFi Cert");
try {
intent.putExtra("CERT",cert.getEncoded());
} 
catch (CertificateEncodingException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
SU1X.debug("error on cert install");
}
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Thought i would just update this in case anyone else is trying to do the same thing and found this question.