# Android, configure Wifi Enterprise PEAP & EAP-Fast

Tags: android, wifi, enterprise

I am writing an application to help test android devices' capabilities to connect to wlan's with varying security settings (ex.  wpa aes peap).  However, I noticed that the published android.net.wifi api does not contain fields to set parameters needed for peap and eap-fast authentication. Does anybody know how to establish a connection to peap programatically?

Below is a link that shows the WifiConfiguration() class possessing unpublished fields (ex. eap, phase2, identity, password). However, eclipse will not let me utilize these fields in my code since they are not officially in the android api.

http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.6/frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.java

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem. The solution is to use "Reflection".

Here is a link that should be very applicable to you.

[How to programmatically create and read WEP/EAP WiFi configurations in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android)