# How to connect to wi-fi network programatically?

Tags: java, android

I am making Android application, and I need to know how I can connect to a wi-fi network programatically. Please give me an example or some other guidance. Thank you.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android

Answer (score 0):

So before anything, you have to allow your app Internet access in the Manifest. Put this in your Manifest body:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Connecting to sites is explained very well here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Please let me know if anything in it is confusing.