# Captive portal with android hotspot programmatically configured

Tags: android, wifi

Is there a way to build on top of a WEP Wifi configuration a Captive portal?

The hotspot is started using this code:
[How to programmatically create and read WEP/EAP WiFi configurations in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android/4375874#4375874)

The idea is to ask a user for a login before actually sharing the data connection.