# Android: Why doesn't the SDK provide for the programmer to add WiFi profiles (EAP) easily?

Tags: android, sdk, android-wifi

I am trying to programmatically create enterprise WiFi profiles on Android (WPA-Enterprise, WPA2-Enterprise).

I have seen a fairly famous solution, which is to use reflection in order to achieve this. To my understanding, if it has to be done in such indirect manner which involves gaining access to portions of an API that have been denied access to, there has to be a good reason for it.

Does this mean that Google does NOT want developers to be able programmatically configure WiFi settings ? If so, what could be the reason for this ?

Comment: Where is this 'fairly famous solution' you have seen?

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android/4375874#4375874

Answer (score 2):

Android JellyBean 4.3 has added this functionality to it's API:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiEnterpriseConfig.html

Comment: ! did you implement for 802.1x EAP with PEAP EPA method? if any one have implemented please share i am stacked on it.

Answer (score 1):

I have written  a class with a static method that will allow you to do this. Here it is. You will need to pass your SSID, Username, and Password into the method. There are some other options you can set if you need to set the EAP to TLS or PEAP. It should be noted that this code is base off of the code here: [How to programmatically create and read WEP/EAP WiFi configurations in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android/4375874#4375874). The difference being that my code allows you to adjust the IP configuration settings and the proxy settings. Using this code you can automatically connect to a wifi network with WPA_EAP settings.

Hope this helps:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.util.Log;

public class WPAConfiguration {

    private static final String INT_PRIVATE_KEY = "private_key";
    private static final String INT_PHASE2 = "phase2";
    private static final String INT_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String INT_IDENTITY = "identity";
    private static final String INT_EAP = "eap";
    private static final String INT_CLIENT_CERT = "client_cert";
    private static final String INT_CA_CERT = "ca_cert";
    private static final String INT_ANONYMOUS_IDENTITY = "anonymous_identity";
    private static final String INT_ENTERPRISEFIELD_NAME = "android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration$EnterpriseField";
    private static final String INT_IPASSIGNMENT_NAME = "android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration$IpAssignment"; 
    private static final String INT_PROXYSETTINGS_NAME = "android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration$ProxySettings";
    //change this to TLS,PEAP, or other options that are listed when you connect via a device
    private static final String ENTERPRISE_EAP = "PEAP";
    private static final String INT_IP_ASSIGNMENT = "ipAssignment";
    private static final String INT_PROXY_SETTINGS = "proxySettings";


    public static WifiConfiguration setWifiConfigurations(WifiConfiguration wifiConfig, String SSID, String userName, String userPass)
    {
        /*define basic configuration settings*/

        /*Access Point*/
        wifiConfig.SSID = SSID; 
        wifiConfig.networkId = 0; 

        /*Priority*/
        wifiConfig.priority = 0; 

        /*Enable Hidden SSID's*/
        wifiConfig.hiddenSSID = false; 

        /*Key Management*/
        wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);
        wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);

        /*Set Group Ciphers*/

        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.clear(); 
        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);


         /*Set Pairwise Ciphers*/

        wifiConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
        wifiConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);

        /*Set Protocols*/

        wifiConfig.allowedProtocols.clear();
        wifiConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        wifiConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);


        /*Set Enterprise Settings Using Reflection*/
        try
        {
            Class<?> wifiEnterpriseField = null; 
            Class<?> wifiIpAssignmentField = null; 
            Class<?> wifiProxySettingsField = null; 

            boolean enterpriseFieldType = true; 
            boolean ipAssignmentFieldType = true; 
            boolean proxySettingsFieldType = true; 

            Field anonymousId = null, caCert = null, clientCert = null, eap = null, identity = null, password = null, phase2 = null, privateKey = null, ipAssignment = null, proxy = null; 

            Method setValue = null; 

            Class<?>[] wifiClasses = WifiConfiguration.class.getClasses(); 

            /*Get Enterprise/IP Assignment/Proxy Setting Field Class to Modify*/
            for(Class<?> wifiClass : wifiClasses)
            {
                if(wifiClass.getName().equals(INT_ENTERPRISEFIELD_NAME))
                {
                    wifiEnterpriseField = wifiClass; 
                }
                else if(wifiClass.getName().equals(INT_IPASSIGNMENT_NAME))
                {
                    wifiIpAssignmentField = wifiClass; 
                }
                else if(wifiClass.getName().equals(INT_PROXYSETTINGS_NAME))
                {
                    wifiProxySettingsField = wifiClass; 
                }
            }

            /*Certain OS (Cupcake & Doughnut) access the enterprise field directly*/
            if(wifiEnterpriseField == null)
            {
                enterpriseFieldType = false; 
            }
            if(wifiIpAssignmentField == null)
            {
                ipAssignmentFieldType = false; 
            }
            if(wifiProxySettingsField == null)
            {
                proxySettingsFieldType = false; 
            }

            /*Get Fields*/
            Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Getting Fields "); 
            Field[] wifiFields = WifiConfiguration.class.getFields();
            for(Field wifiField : wifiFields)
            {
                if(wifiField.getName().equals(INT_ANONYMOUS_IDENTITY))
                {
                    anonymousId = wifiField;
                    Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Getting Field: " + wifiField); 
                }
                else if(wifiField.getName().equals(INT_CA_CERT))
                {
                    caCert = wifiField;
                    Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Getting Field: " + wifiField);
                }
                else if(wifiField.getName().equals(INT_CLIENT_CERT))
                {
                    clientCert = wifiField; 
                    Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Getting Field: " + wifiField);
                }
                else if(wifiField.getName().equals(INT_EAP))
                {
                    eap = wifiField;
                    Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Getting Field: " + wifiField);
                }
                else if(wifiField.getName().equals(INT_IDENTITY))
                {
                    identity = wifiField; 
                    Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Getting Field: " + wifiField);
                }
                else if(wifiField.getName().equals(INT_PASSWORD))
                {
                    password = wifiField; 
                    Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Getting Field: " + wifiField);
                }
                else if(wifiField.getName().equals(INT_PHASE2))
                {
                    phase2 = wifiField; 
                    Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Getting Field: " + wifiField);
                }
                else if(wifiField.getName().equals(INT_PRIVATE_KEY))
                {
                    privateKey = wifiField; 
                    Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Getting Field: " + wifiField);
                }
                else if(wifiField.getName().equals(INT_IP_ASSIGNMENT))
                {
                    ipAssignment = wifiField; 
                    Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Getting Field: " + wifiField);
                }
                else if(wifiField.getName().equals(INT_PROXY_SETTINGS))
                {
                    proxy = wifiField; 
                    Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Getting Field: " + wifiField);
                }

            }

            /*Get method to set value of enterprise fields*/
            if(enterpriseFieldType)
            {
                for(Method method : wifiEnterpriseField.getMethods())
                {
                    Log.d("Get Methods", "Enterprise Method: " + method);
                    if(method.getName().trim().equals("setValue"))
                    {
                        setValue = method; 
                        break;  
                    }
                }
            }

            /*Set EAP*/
            if(enterpriseFieldType)
            {
                setValue.invoke(eap.get(wifiConfig), ENTERPRISE_EAP);
                Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Setting " + ENTERPRISE_EAP); 
            }
            else
            {
                eap.set(wifiConfig, ENTERPRISE_EAP); 
            }

            /*Set Identity*/
            if(enterpriseFieldType)
            {
                setValue.invoke(identity.get(wifiConfig), userName); 
                Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Setting " + userName); 
            }
            else
            {
                identity.set(wifiConfig, userName); 
            }

            /*Set user password*/
            if(enterpriseFieldType)
            {
                setValue.invoke(password.get(wifiConfig), userPass); 
                Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Setting " + userPass); 
            }
            else
            {
                password.set(wifiConfig, userPass); 
            }

            /*Set IP Protocol*/
            if(ipAssignmentFieldType)
            {
                /*Change the literal string in here to change the value of obtaining and IP address*/
                ipAssignment.set(wifiConfig, Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) ipAssignment.getType().asSubclass(Enum.class), "DHCP")); 
                Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Setting " + ipAssignment); 
            }
            else
            {
                ipAssignment.set(wifiConfig, "DHCP"); 
            }

            /*Set Proxy Protocol*/
            if(proxySettingsFieldType)
            {
                /*Change the literal string in here to change the value of proxy settingss*/
                proxy.set(wifiConfig, Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) proxy.getType().asSubclass(Enum.class), "NONE"));
                Log.d("Enterprise Setting", "Setting " + proxy); 
            }
            else
            {
                proxy.set(wifiConfig, "NONE"); 
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR!!!", "Error: " + e);

        }
        Log.d("WIFI", "Configuration Settings " + wifiConfig.toString()); 
        return wifiConfig;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have seen this solution before. This is not a direct SDK method, but rather a reflection hack. These holes can be blocked by Google at any give time.

Comment: @HeshanPerera you are write from lolipop on wards those technique in not working. is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something in the question or in the details, as I've not had a need to do this myself, but do the [`WifiManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) and [`WifiConfiguration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html) classes not do what you need? For example:

```
WifiManager wMan = getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();

config.SSID = "your ssid";
//continue setting up the configuration

wMan.addNetwork(config);
```

EDIT: The answer you pointed to only uses reflection for EAP configurations (connections using WPA-Enterprise or WPA2-Enterprise security, typically). For typical connections, you shouldn't have to use reflection.

Comment: That is correct. But my requirement is for Enterprise. Is there a reason why this should be dis-allowed for enterprise ?

Comment: Okay, with that clarification I'm not sure then. I'm not particularly familiar with EAP networks so I'll leave that answer to someone else. :)

Comment: Thank you, please share this with someone who may know the answer ?