# Connecting WEP wireless networks in Android is not doing anything in my app

Tags: android, wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect to a specific wifi network in android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)

I have been trying out various ways to connect WEP wireless networks using the following links:

[How do I connect to a specific Wi-Fi network in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)

OR

[How to programmatically create and read WEP/EAP WiFi configurations in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android/4374934#4374934)

I also tried the quotes and no quotes for the password. doesn't come up at all. Also a combination of both the above links too.

This is the last I tried:

```
networkSSID = bundle.getString("networkName");
networkPass = bundle.getString("networkPassword");

WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\""; 
conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40); 
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass is" + networkPass ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id is" + networkSSID ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
   if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
    wifiManager.reconnect();                
        break;
   }           
}
```

I am not sure where the issue is - when I connect manually to the same WEP network through the settings I am able to connect it.

It will be great if somebody can give me a correct solution on how to connect it?

Let me know!!

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a duplicate.. As entered above I have tried all the ideas given the in link nothing worked that is why I posted this message.

Comment: I guess WEP is really an issue on android programatically?