# how to connect with a wifi network from a generated list of wifi networks?

Tags: android, wifi

I have generated a list of available wifi networks near my android device. 
Now I want to open a dialog box asking for password if i click any wifi network from list, and if I enter right password then it must get connected to that wifi network. how can I do it.

Comment: Please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android/13803100#13803100

Comment: Above link will give you clarity on how to create a wifi connection if ssid(scanned network) & password is available