# Install Wifi profile by button

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-wifi

I'n not sure where to start in Eclipse.

I want to create an layout with some textboxes (username / Password) and a button "Send"

When the user fill in their username and password, a wireless profile (TTLS/MSCHAPV2) has to be installed with their username/password.

So far i got the button with the onclick function.

mainactivity.java.
`(public void installprofile(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button`

Now i have to place the wifi config code.
How do i let the code know which username/password he need for installing the profile ?

It has to take the username/password from the textboxes.

Kind Regards
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [SO 'question'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android?rq=1), It outlines the general idea of what you're trying to do. I would have commented on the original post, but I don't have enough rep.