# Set Channel of Android HotSpot

Tags: java, android, reflection

Is there a way to set the used Channel for the Android Hotspot?

I know there is no official API for this but are there some way using reflection?

Edit: I found some hints at stackoverflow that i meay be possible:

```
Field wcAdhocFreq = WifiConfiguration.class.getField("frequency");
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4375874/441907), but i couldn't find that field in the sources..

Comment: It's clearly written in the post you provided, that "frequency" can be set only in CM (CyanogenMod) Android ROM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not

Everything that application can configure is contained in a [parcelable WifiConfiguration](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.java) and it doesn't include the channel.

Comment: See my edited question, there seems to be (at least in some android version) a field named "frequency" in WifiConfiguration.

Comment: looks like it is a CyanogenMod extension

Answer (score 0):

You can use the channel field:

```
Field wcFreq = WifiConfiguration.class.getField("channel");
wcFreq.setInt(wifiConf, 1);
```

This will change the hotspot to channel 1.