# How can I programmatically read wifi passwords in Android

Tags: android, wifi, manifest

I am trying to get the WiFi passwords programmatically from a non-rooted Android device.

All I need is to be able to read the passwords, I do not need to be able to edit them.

Can I get permission in the manifest file?

Comment: This question has answers that claim to work for earlier versions of Android, but don't work for more recent versions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android

Answer (score 9):

If your application is a privileged app (that is - installed in `/system/priv-app` for example using SuperUser) then you can use the new `WifiManager#getPrivilegedConfiguredNetworks()` API in Lollipop and newer.

See: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/758bdf4a915c313f1c3bef0b95b494c91f363f03%5E%21/#F1

Comment: I wonder if this is how the Google Home app does it when onboarding chromecast/home devices. It really does make the onboarding slicker.

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible as this would be a major security risk.

You may be able to if the phone is rooted but I do not know, I would imagine, and hope, even if you could get to where it is stored on the phone, it would be encrypted.

Comment: can i get the password of the connected wifi network ?

Comment: No, again this would be a security risk, and why would you need to, if you are connected, you probably know the password

Comment: Google Chromecast (now Home) can read current wifi password and provide it to Chromecast...

Comment: Well, Home has the necessary privileges to do so, it's unfair, but it's Google ;)

Answer (score 7):

Most of the time, the Wi-Fi credentials are managed by the [`wpa_supplicant`](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/) daemon which store this in a configuration file like `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

In this file you will find `network` structures which store the remembered networks like this:

```
network={
    ssid="example"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    psk="passphrase"
}
```

This file is usually own by a system user like `wifi` or `root`. So you have to be `root` if you want to read it directly.

Nevertheless, you can get the `ssid` or other network variables of the remember networks by using the `wpa_cli` command:

```
$ wpa_cli get_network <id> ssid
"example"
```

But if you try with the `psk` you will get a `*` as this is a security risk:

```
$ wpa_cli get_network <id> psk
*
```

Comment: This file doesn't have such information in latest android (kitkat). How to do it in kitkat?

Answer (score 3):

There is no API support for reading/writing WiFi passwords for APKs not signed with the system key. So you won't be able to retrieve it.

Comment: can i get the password of the connected wifi network ?

Comment: Passwords of connected WiFi networks are stored in your phone. But you need Root Access to read this file.