# How to read saved wifi passowrd without root[su] access

Tags: android, android-wifi, google-home, wifimanager

I need to read saved **wifi password** for one of application. 
I know that it is not possible directly due to security issues, but by rooting the android mobile device, It might because.[I don't want this solution].

But **Google Home android application** is allowed to read the saved WiFi passwords. How could it be possible?

I read few posts on SO and I came to know that only system apps can have access to it.

On [WifiManager.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java), we have a method to handle it [getPrivilegedConfiguredNetwork()](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/06ad45a59677d48f7f1dce850b5709b64985a43f/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java#L1241), but this method is hidden & only system apps can access it.

```
/** @hide */
@SystemApi
@RequiresPermission(allOf = {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, READ_WIFI_CREDENTIAL})
public List<WifiConfiguration> getPrivilegedConfiguredNetworks() {
    try {
        ParceledListSlice<WifiConfiguration> parceledList =
                mService.getPrivilegedConfiguredNetworks(mContext.getOpPackageName());
        if (parceledList == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return parceledList.getList();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw e.rethrowFromSystemServer();
    }
}
```

Can this method help on reading the Wifi password?

Comment: looks similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21330520/5372462

Comment: No. My question is different. Please read completely. Google Home android application is allowed to read the saved WiFi passwords. How could it be possible?

Comment: This may provide a more complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752656/whats-the-meaning-of-new-systemapi-annotation-any-difference-from-hide. In a nutshell, any attempt to use `getPrivilegedConfiguredNetworks`, even via reflection, will result in an `invocationTargetException`. Without root privileges, you will not be able to access that API.

Comment: @rfestag please check my previous comment.