# How to hide SSID on android phone

Tags: android, networking, wifi, tethering

I am trying to hide SSID on my android phone. Can anyone please how to proceed for it? Is there any Android API available for the same?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please keep in mind, that hiding the SSID is not seen as a useful thing: http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/08/3-reasons-why-hiding-wireless-ssid-bad-idea/ or https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r26832064-Internet-Is-hiding-wireless-SSID-a-good-idea-does-it-cause-pr

Answer (score 1):

You can not hide AP SSID (stop SSID broadcasting or beaconing) through Android API!

SSID hiding depends on the kernel/wifi-driver that you have on your phone! Only few drivers (devices) support this feature! Also a few drivers support monitor mode! 
Vendor-drivers have closed source :-(  which makes it difficult to add these features to them! See [bcmon](https://code.google.com/p/bcmon/) project for example)

Android API allows you to connect to the network with specific SSID (it may be hided) programmatically. You should know network SSID and password (see this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html#hiddenSSID) about `WifiConfiguration` class and `hiddenSSID`, this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) about `WifiManager` class, and these stackoverflow answers: [programmatically create WiFi Configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android), [connect to a specific WiFi network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)).

See this 3rd party App [HiddenSSID Enabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.sourceforge.soopy.hidden.ssid.enabler&hl=ru&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dandroid+connect+hidden+ssid&pcampaignid=APPU_thm4VJG9MKmaygPQ4oLAAQ) for connecting to AP with hided SSID and this example: [Connecting your Android tablet to a wireless network with disabled SSID broadcast](http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/GetArticle.aspx?docid=044d2d53b3a74536827a035797cf2f9d_Connecting_your_Android_tablet_to_a_wireless_network_with_di.xml&pid=82&converted=0)

Comment: Some Samsung devices have this feature to hide the phone.

Answer (score -3):

When SSID is hidden at wifi, you may not use wifi.
This software enable hidden SSID.
NOTE: This software will change wifi settings,
take responsibility by yourself.

[Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.sourceforge.soopy.hidden.ssid.enabler&hl=en)

Comment: i know its 2019, but this part "**When SSID is hidden at wifi, you may not use wifi**" the information is a bit misleading. i have no idea about the app though.