# Configure EAP-SIM for dual SIM devices in Android

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I've tried configuring EAP-SIM for single SIM devices and got connected successfully. Now I want to configure for a specific SIM card on a dual SIM device.

My observation is while configuring EAP in single SIM device, there is no provision to specify the SIM identity. So how can I configure EAP with a specific SIM ?

Configuring EAP-SIM for single SIM device:

```
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiEnterpriseConfig enterpriseConfig = new WifiEnterpriseConfig();
    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifiConfig.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
    wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
    wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);
    enterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.SIM);
    wifiConfig.enterpriseConfig = enterpriseConfig;
    int nid = wifi.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
    wifi.saveConfiguration();
    wifi.enableNetwork(nid, true);
```

Comment: Did you get a way of configuring EAP-SIM for dual SIM devices in Android ?

Comment: No, I could not configure EAP-SIM for dual SIM devices.

Comment: Did you tried setting EAP method as AKA

Comment: @Kishore Did you find the answer?

Comment: @mudit_sen nope.!

Comment: @Kishore Hehe I did.

Comment: @mudit_sen Great.! I think the project I was working got scrapped and I didn't have to look more for the answer, It remained a mystery, anyways thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer helped me a lot.

[How to programmatically create and read WEP/EAP WiFi configurations in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programmatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android/4374934)

This is how you configure Wifi with EAP Sim.

```
        private fun getWifiConfigurationForAirtelEAP(ssId: String,sim:String):WifiConfiguration{
            val wifiConfiguration = WifiConfiguration()
            wifiConfiguration.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssId);
            wifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = false
            wifiConfiguration.BSSID = null

            wifiConfiguration.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN)

            wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP)
            wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP)
            wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104)
            wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40)

            wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP)
            wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)

            wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP)
            wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP)

            wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN)
            wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA)

            wifiConfiguration.enterpriseConfig = getWifiEnterpriseConfig(sim)

            return wifiConfiguration
        }

        private fun getWifiEnterpriseConfig(sim: String): WifiEnterpriseConfig {
            val enterpriseConfig = WifiEnterpriseConfig()
            enterpriseConfig.eapMethod = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.SIM
            enterpriseConfig.anonymousIdentity = "NULL"
            val field = enterpriseConfig.javaClass.getDeclaredField("mFields");
            field.isAccessible =true
            val values = (field.get(enterpriseConfig) as HashMap<String,String>)
            values.put(SIM_NUM,"\""+sim+"\"")
            values.put(CLIENT_CERT,"NULL")
            values.put(KEY_ID,"NULL")
            values.put(ENGINE,"0")
            values.put(ENGINE_ID,"NULL")
            values.put(IDENTITY,"NULL")
            values.put(CA_PATH,"NULL")
            values.put(DOMAIN_SUFFIX_MATCH,"NULL")
            values.put(CA_CERT,"NULL")
            values.put(PASSWORD,"NULL")
            values.put(ANONYMOUS_IDENTITY,"NULL")
            return enterpriseConfig
        }
```