# Unable to connect to a specific Wifi network programmatically on Android

Tags: android

I want to design an app which shows a list of wifi networks available and connect to the network when it is selected. I have implemented the part showing the scan results. Now i want to connect to a particular network selected by the user from the list of scan results. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    wifiReciever = new WiFiScanReceiver();


}

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {

    adapter.clear();

    ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) view;

    if (wifiManager == null) {
        // Device does not support Wi-Fi
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oop! Your device does not support Wi-Fi",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);

    } else {
        if (toggleButton.isChecked()) { // To turn on Wi-Fi
            if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wi-Fi is turned on." +
                                "\n" + "Scanning for access points...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wi-Fi is already turned on." +
                                "\n" + "Scanning for access points...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            wifiManager.startScan();

        } else { // To turn off Wi-Fi
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wi-Fi is turned off.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }
    }


}

class WiFiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        //if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
        //    wifiScanResult = wifiManager.getScanResults();


        if (WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanResultList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanResultList.size(); i++) {
                ScanResult accessPoint = wifiScanResultList.get(i);
                //wifiScanList[i] = wifiScanResultList.get(i).SSID;
                String listItem = " Name: " + accessPoint.SSID +    " \n Mac: " + accessPoint.BSSID + "\n Signal Strenght: " + accessPoint.level+ "dBm";
                adapter.add(listItem);
                // }
                // }
                //listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifiScanList));


            }
        }


    }
}








@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.wi_fi, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fire up this method on each item selected from your listview:

```
  static public void ConnectToWiFi(String ssid ,String key,Context ctx) {

    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
    wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", key);
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) ctx.getSystemService(ctx.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int networkId = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
    wifiManager.removeNetwork(networkId);
    wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
    //remember id
    int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    wifiManager.reconnect();
}
```

enter the item's SSID and key/password and you can drop the Context if not needed.
good luck

Comment: @praveen key is the wifi password

Comment: @ Martin Pfeffer remove for the case key-pass was wrong and network is in saved mode

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer will not work for Oreo+! We need to specify properly the wificonfig to connec to the specific Wifi network.
I had the similar usecase which i did resolve using some common sense. The wifi which we are going to connect should be avialable right? This means that if we scan the wifi manager then in the List of ScanResult there should be the device with SSID == MySSID, In this matching scanResult we also have the security type possessed by the scanned item, that will help us to make a more specific WifiConfig for WPA2 and WEP, Make sense?

Okay so here we go step by step!
 1. Create a Wifi manager instance, and call startScan on it like

> mWifiManager.startScan()

, upon calling this the scanlist of the available devices is received through the BroadcastReceiver whose OnReceive should look like this:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
            List<ScanResult> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
            for (ScanResult res :
                    mScanResults) {
                if (!isConnected && res.SSID.contains(networkSSID)) {
                    networkSSID = res.SSID;
                    connectthis(res);
                }
            }
```

2. The connect this method should look like this:

```
private void connectthis(ScanResult res) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", res.SSID);
    wifiConfig.BSSID = res.BSSID;
    wifiConfig.priority = 40;
    if (res.capabilities.toLowerCase().contains("wep")) {
        wifiConfig.wepKeys[0] = String.format("\"%s\"", networkKey);
        wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        wifiConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        wifiConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        wifiConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
        wifiConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
        wifiConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
    } else if (res.capabilities.toLowerCase().contains("wpa")) {
        wifiConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        wifiConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        wifiConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", networkKey);
    }


    if (networkKey.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    WifiManager wifiManager = 
   (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    boolean isConfigured = false;
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
        if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            wifiManager.reconnect();
            isConfigured = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //adding the network
    if (!isConfigured) {
        int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
        wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this code works for the wifi networks with wep and wap encryption strategy. Please check the encryption strategy supported by your wifi network and mold the code accordingly.

Comment: The WiFi I am testing on is open. there is no security. Public WiFi

Comment: for that just use wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
And provide the ssid in wificonfiguration to get the networkID and enable it.

Comment: @SaadurRehman I just tested it on an Android 9 (P) and it works great. But on an Android 10 (Q) it unfortunately does not work anymore. The documentation confirms it here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#reconnect()

Comment: @GeraldoNeto i have been using the same code for android Q, the reconnect api is deprecated but the wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true); api should reconnect when called. Please check and let me know if i can be of any help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below links will be a good starting point for you to understand android WiFi Manager and connecting to a particular network.

1. [How to connect to a specific WiFi network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)
2. [Create and manage WiFi Configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android?lq=1)

Hope this helps.