# Is there any way to set auto connect WiFi in android programatically

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking

I have a question, Is there any get or set method for auto connection so that I can set auto connect true or false for selected wifi.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374862/how-to-programmatically-create-and-read-wep-eap-wifi-configurations-in-android/4374934#4374934

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/connecting-your-app-to-wi-fi-device.html

Comment: I would hope that the user needs to confirm the connection at least the first time. Automatically connecting someone to a WiFi without their consent feels like a pretty serious security issue if it was possible.

Comment: @Michael they have to authenticate  first and there is a switch to set auto connect true or false.

Comment: @Hubertoss I am doing this to connect a WiFi but,auto connect wifi I am not getting.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure whether this is possibile ,but I would try to ask user to set auto connection for the wifi network and investigate if you can programaticallt assign top-priority to the network SSID that your app uses.

Comment: Is that possible in rooted device? If yes then how?